# ModelState.IsValid in false

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, controller

i have a problem, im trynin to modify the model before send it to save, adding some data to the model, but the model its not getting the change, and the modelState.IsValid propierty stay in false. Why?

```
  public ActionResult EditarTipoArchivo(TipoArchivos tipoarchivos)
    {
        TipoArchivos tipoArchivos = TipoArchivoRepository.GetTipoArchivosById(tipoarchivos.TipoArchivoId);
        TipoSolicitud tiposolicitud = TipoSolicitudRepository.GetTipoSolicitudById(tipoarchivos.TipoSolicitudId);

        tipoarchivos.CodigoTipoSolicitud = tiposolicitud.Codigo;
        tipoarchivos.TipoArchivoId = tipoArchivos.TipoArchivoId;
        tipoarchivos.Codigo = tipoArchivos.Codigo;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TipoArchivoRepository.GuardarTipoArchivos(tipoarchivos);
            TempData["message"] = String.Format("El {0} ha sido actualizado correctamente", tipoarchivos.TipoArchivoId);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {


            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Ha sucedido un inconveniente al intentar actualizar el Tipo de Archivo");
            return View(tipoarchivos);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear ModelState (ModelState.Clear()), then 
validate it again

```
Ex:
  if (TryValidateModel(modelVM))
   {
     ...
   }
```